# Squaring $\sqrt{(x-2)^{2}+(y-3)^{2}}=\frac{|5x+6y+5|}{\sqrt{5^{2}+6^{2}}}$ does not lose information?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving, intuition, radicals

**Scenario 1:**

$$y=3x+5\tag{1}$$

$$y^{2}=\left(3x+5\right)^{2}\tag{2}$$

When both sides are squared in $(1)$, we lose some information and get $(2)$: the [graphs](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mxfkbjpemn) of $(1)$ and $(2)$ aren't the same.

**Scenario 2:**

$$\sqrt{\left(x-2\right)^{2}+\left(y-3\right)^{2}}=\frac{\left|5x+6y+5\right|}{\sqrt{5^{2}+6^{2}}}\tag{3}$$

$$\left(x-2\right)^{2}+\left(y-3\right)^{2}=\frac{\left(5x+6y+5\right)^{2}}{5^{2}+6^{2}}\tag{4}$$

The [graphs](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jilfdouz6w) of $(3)$ and $(4)$ are exactly the same! When both sides are squared in $(3)$, we get $(4)$, and no information is lost in the process: the two graphs are identical!

**Question**

1. Why is information preserved in scenario 2, i.e. the graphs of $(3)$ & $(4)$ are identical, when information is lost in scenario 1, i.e. the graphs of $(1)$ & $(2)$ aren't identical?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equation "$A^2=B^2$" is equivalent to "$A=B$ or $A=-B$".

In your first example, both $y = 3x+5$ and $y = -(3x+5)$ are perfectly possible, and $y^2 = (3x+5)^2$ combines those.

In your second example, both $\sqrt{\left(x-2\right)^{2}+\left(y-3\right)^{2}}$ and $\frac{\left|5x+6y+5\right|}{\sqrt{5^{2}+6^{2}}}$  are guaranteed to be positive, so one cannot be the negative of the other; only the $A=B$ case is a possibility to begin with.

In other words: by squaring both sides, we are adding in all points which satisfy $$\sqrt{\left(x-2\right)^{2}+\left(y-3\right)^{2}} = -\frac{\left|5x+6y+5\right|}{\sqrt{5^{2}+6^{2}}}$$ but there are no such points.

Comment: Notice that the last equation has a solution in complex numbers, so the same issues are restored if we move to the 'right' setting to judge these problems.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, all the terms in (3) and (4)
are already positive:
the $\sqrt{}$ argument
is the sum of squares
and the absolute value term
is, by definition,
always non-negative.

So there are no negative values
for the squaring to
make positive
and therefore create
an extraneous root.

Answer (score 1):

$
|a|=|b|\iff a^2=b^2\kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies     a=b\implies a^2=b^2.$